# Function not being run

Tags: function, powershell

I have the following function:

```
 function CheckNagiosConfig {

# Query nConf for hosts
Invoke-Expression -command $nconf_command_host | Out-file $nconf_export_host_file
$nconf_export_host = Import-Csv $nconf_export_host_file -Delimiter ";" 

# Query nConf for services
Invoke-Expression -command $nconf_command_service | Out-file $nconf_export_service_file
$nconf_export_service = Import-Csv $nconf_export_service_file -Delimiter ";" 

return $nconf_export_host
return $nconf_export_service
}
```

but when I call this with CheckNagiosConfig nothing is being run.. What am I missing?
And, am I returning the variables correctly? Is this the way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First your function ends on first return (return $nconf_export_host), the second one is never seen. If you want to return mutliple things (an array) you shoud use `Write-Output` CmdLet.

---

Edited

For returning vars you've got at least three solutions :

1) Working on the scope with a global var by writting

```
$global:nconf_export_host = Import-Csv $nconf_export_host_file -Delimiter ";"
```

or

```
$script:nconf_export_host = Import-Csv $nconf_export_host_file -Delimiter ";"
```

You can use `$nconf_export_host` outside the function.

2) Passing arguments to function by reference

```
function CheckNagiosConfig ([ref]$nconf_export_host, [ref]$$nconf_export_service)
{
  ...
  $nconf_export_host.value = Import-Csv $nconf_export_host_file -Delimiter ";" 

  ...
  $nconf_export_service.value = Import-Csv $nconf_export_service_file -Delimiter ";" 

  return $true
}
```

In this case, you can keep the semantic of the returned value to specify how the function works, and you can modify inside the function, the arguments passed by reference.

3) Using the output itself

```
function CheckNagiosConfig {

# Query nConf for hosts
Invoke-Expression -command $nconf_command_host | Out-file $nconf_export_host_file
$nconf_export_host = Import-Csv $nconf_export_host_file -Delimiter ";" 
write-output $nconf_export_host

# Query nConf for services
Invoke-Expression -command $nconf_command_service | Out-file $nconf_export_service_file
$nconf_export_service = Import-Csv $nconf_export_service_file -Delimiter ";" 

return $nconf_export_service
}
```

used with :

```
$a = CheckNagiosConfig
# $a[0] will be $nconf_export_host
# $a[1] will be $nconf_export_service
```

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up! But how do I return variables created from a function then?

Comment: I edited my answer to explain you multiple ways to return vars.